# ngRepeat:iexp Invalid Expression when render the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Html

```
                    <tr ng-repeat="sale as examples">
                        <td class="text-right"> @{{sale.sales_person}}</td> 
                        <td class="text-right"> @{{sale.sales_total}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right"> @{{sale.sales_target_amount}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right"> @{{sale.sales_target_total}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

JS

```
            $scope.getMonthlySalesTarget = function () {
                $scope.sales_target_loading = true;
                bz_Dashboard.getMonthlySalesTarget($scope.sales_target.startdate, $scope.sales_target.enddate).then(function (data) {
                    $scope.sales_target.data = angular.copy(data);
                    $scope.examples = $scope.sales_target.data;
                    console.log($scope.examples);

                }).finally(function () {
                    $scope.sales_target_loading = false;
                });
            };
```

I'm trying to load the using ng-repeat but I faced that error. The `$scope.examples` stored a lists of data as.
Json

```
[{"sales_total":"386.90","sales_target_amount":"30000.00","sales_person":"Tony","sales_target_total":29613.1}]
```

I suspecting the error is triggered by data access issue so I did try to add the $index as `sale as examples by $index` but it does not work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ng-repeat="sale in sales"` rather than `sale as examples`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use 'in' instead of 'as' in ng-repeat .

ng-repeat="sale in examples"